# How to utilize the javascript object in mongo aggregate query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have a object like this

```
const obj = {'id_1': 'data_1', 'id_2': 'data_2'....}
```

And I have an aggregate query like this:

```
        models.dummy.aggregate(
          [
            { $match: findQuery },
            {
              $project: {
                id: 1,
                tId: 1,
                quantity: 1,
                status: 1,
                notes:
             }
            }
          ]);
```

Now here for `notes` field in $project, I want to save the result `obj['tId']` for it. I'm not able to figure how do I access the object `obj` in the aggregate query and utilise the `tId` to associate the `notes` field with the value.

Expected output for `notes`

```
notes: obj[tId]

// O/P:
[
 {
  notes: 'data_1';
  ...

 },
 {
  notes: 'data_2';
  ...

 }
...
]
```

Comment: just say `notes: $tId`

Comment: @varman actually i want to access the value for the key `tId` from `obj`. `obj[tId]`

Comment: can u update the question that shows tId and expected output

Comment: @varman updated

Comment: Does that mean you need to update `notes` fieldname for `id_1`, `id_2` ... If Im wrong, please elaborate more

Comment: @varman I want to use the `tId` from the $project, which also happens to be the key values for the javascript object `obj`. Now I want to use this `tId` key, to save the `obj['tId']` in the notes field.

Comment: According to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#embedded-document-fields this doesn't appear to be possible.

Comment: If you want to insert data from client into aggregation pipeline result, that's not possible either but you can assemble the result set you want on the client.

Comment: @D.SM okay, thanks for pointing me in a direction. I spent an entire day just for this thinking that maybe this could be possible.